# Command line won't let me type, in the midst of a Rails Console session

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, bash, terminal

In Rails console I entered an Active Record query, and it took up more than the whole screen, so it was scrolling. I forgot to hit `q` to get out of it and instead hit `Ctrl-C`. I got some errors, then I got some of the Rails console output, then I hit ^C again, then my prompt came up...

But I can't type anything. Well, actually I can type, but I can't see anything.

If I type `exit` it will exit the Rails console and get me back to my prompt, and then if I type `rails c` I'll get back to my console. Except none of the things I just mentioned typing *appear on the screen when I type them.*

And once I'm back inside the console I still can't see what I'm typing. I have to open a new terminal.

I've had this happen in a number of different scenarios, probably all where my reflexes exited a process the wrong way (like with ^C instead of q), and this is just the first one where I could pin it down.

Does anyone know how to fix this without having to scrap my work and open a new terminal?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Something you've typed, or something output from your query in console, has disabled or redirected the "echo" setting in your shell - so, you're still able to type commands, but you just can't see them.  If the Active Record query returned binary data, it's quite likely that some bytes of the binary data happened to be an escape code that changed your echo setting.  It's also important to realize that if your echo setting changed, it's quite possible that other settings have changed as well.

If you're at your shell prompt, you would just type the unix command `reset` to restore normal settings.  However, if you're still in your Rails console, you'll need to type:

```
system 'reset'
```

to run that command from Ruby.

Comment: Thanks for this detailed answer! I’ll mark it as the correct one once I find myself if this pickle again.

Answer (score 1):

Type [`reset`](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/unix_commands/reset.htm) and press enter, it should be fixed.